# Connect to teradata from VBA and run codes parallerly

Tags: excel, teradata, vba

1. We often have Excel connect to a teradata database and run some sql for various reports/models we produce. If I'm right this will always connect and 'Execute' as per a standard query run in Queryman.
2. However, I'd like to be able to tell it to connect and 'Execute Parallel'.
3. Because my query takes around 2-3 hrs to get the data and if I run it from excel VBA then I am not able to do anything on my Excel application.
4. I want that once i have fired query on teradata, it will run parallerly and my excel is also free for the time required to get the data.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can i start by saying 2 to 3 hours is a long time!

I can only suggest one thing as you haven't got any code to go on and the type of connection is unfamiliar to me:

Excel can open more than one instance of the application, this is completly different to a new workbook within the currently opened one.

There are a few ways to check, the main one is you cannot link to a cell in another instance of excel and I frequently get this when trying to do a `vlookup` between workbooks that are not in the same instance.Also ifyou press `<ctrl> + <c>` to cycle through your workbooks within the curreent instance, other excel instances wont show.

You can open a new instance by right-clicking on the excel on the taskbar and open a new excel. If successfull there will be no issues opening excel.

As an aside, I connect asynchronous to oracle and use a loop that checks the state of the connection and add the `Do Events` function to enable excel to keep woking.

Answer (score 1):

This is to establish 2 separate connections and execute one-by-one:

```
Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objmyconn2 = New ADODB.Connection


objmyconn.Open "Driver={Teradata};DBCName=DB1;Database=DB1;Uid=LUSER1;Pwd=LPWD1;"
objmyconn2.Open "Driver={Teradata};DBCName=DB1;Database=DB1;Uid=LUSR2;Pwd=LPWD2;"

Set RS = objmyconn.Execute("SELECT USER")

While Not RS.EOF
  MsgBox (RS.Fields(0).Value)
  RS.MoveNext
Wend

Set RS2 = objmyconn2.Execute("SELECT USER")

While Not RS2.EOF
  MsgBox (RS2.Fields(0).Value)
  RS2.MoveNext
Wend


objmyconn.Close
objmyconn2.Close
```

For parallel processing, you will need to split the above code into two different procs and install a parallel-processing Excel add-on; this way your two Teradata connections will be executing concurrently.

Or better yet - execute these calls via 2 parallel VBS files, rather than trying to conquer Excel.